# fastest way to sort list of strings

Tags: c#, sorting

I have list of strings like this

"FirstName-Lastname" (separated by a dash -)

I need to sort it this list by first name and then by last name

What is the best way to do this.
i need to process 30000 strings in less than 1 second.

I was suggested to use LINQ to Entities.

what is the best way to use this?

thanks a lot for any help

EDIT: to avoid confusion the input is `List<string>`

Comment: L2E? Is the data in a database or in memory?

Comment: Where does the data come from?

Comment: please show som source code... what have your tried ?

Comment: How long does it take to execute using LINQ to Entities?

Comment: Try some different sorting strategies and profile the results.

Comment: @Slugart: I don't know how to use it. Can you tell me how? thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ (which would allow you to sort without modifying the data in the List):

```
names.OrderBy(s => s.Split('-')[0]).ThenBy(s => s.Split('-')[1]);
```

Comment: @NiklasB. - Depends on the desired behavior if first names overlap. Consider 'Sam-Jones' and 'Samantha-Smith'. Simply calling OrderBy without splitting the values would put Samantha ahead of Sam but I would expect Sam to come first.

Comment: I think you meant (Last then First name): `names.OrderBy(s => s.Split('-')[1]).ThenBy(s => s.Split('-')[0]);`

Comment: @anderson: No, it's first name, then last name, according to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The string might not contain a '-' so the query will crash. can you tell me how to handle that?

Comment: @Youssef - In that case, there's no good way to do what you need. You could try just calling Sort() on the list, but that is going to give you strange results if names overlap.

Comment: @Youssef. If the data is not structured, it's gonna be kind of hard to deal with it.

Comment: I just tested this method on 30,000 randomly-generated names, and it takes about 250 ms as opposed to about 150 ms for `@Niklas` solution.  These are both tested in LINQPad on a 2GHz Core 2 Duo Laptop, which isn't the fastest in the world.  If you want to test it yourself, here's a paste: http://pastebin.com/whwjgMjP

Comment: @mellamokb: Nice! Thanks for this, in that case my solution is superflous.

Comment: You could add a `select` to split the string before ordering it, which would also provide a good place for error validation (i.e. no '-' in the string).  If you did this you wouldn't be splitting it twice.

Comment: Thank a lot it worked, One final thing, if instead of firstname-lasstname we have firstnumber-lastnumber how can I make the sorting to be by integer and not by string? because I want "2" to be smaller than "11" if we sort by string we get 11 then 2

Answer (score 2):

You could also use delegates

```
names.Sort(
    delegate(string str1, string str2)
    {
        return str1.CompareTo(str2);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your array of strings in `26` subarrays, one for each letter of the alphabet. Then repeat the process for each subarray.

This method is very effective for sorting strings. It's known as [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).

Comment: I would use one of the framework sorting functions and only roll my own sort if there was compelling reasons to believe that a) the program isn't fast enough already and b) the newer sorting function would make more of a difference than some other performance enhancement.  There are enough edge cases that the probability of error just isn't worth it considering I'm sure that the quick/merge sort the framework uses is *fast enough*.

Comment: @Servy: For `30000` strings, it probably doesn't matter. But for really large collections of strings, I found bucket sort to be a huge performance benefit.

Comment: I don't doubt that it's faster, I'm simply asserting that *in this case* the benefit isn't worth the risk.  If there were a framework solution that used a Radix sort, or if there was compelling evidence that the performance was needed, then it would be used.  Since that could be true at some future point (or for other readers) this isn't a *wrong* answer (hence no -1 from me).