# Fast way to convert a string to a struct

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have a struct like this

```
typedef struct  
{ 
    string firstname;  
    string lastname;  
} person;
```

As an input I take a List of strings `List<string>` like this

```
"firstname-lastname"
```

What is the fastest way to convert from the input string to the struct person? can it be done by using LINQ?

The string might not contain a '-' in that case the sting will be saved in person.firstname and the person.lastname is empty.

Hope I was clear.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You have asked this question recently as well dealing with speed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997245/fastest-way-to-sort-list-of-strings.  Have you profiled your application to find the actual places where it is needing performance optimization?  It may not be the most productive to optimize the places you *think* need to be fast.

Comment: C# doesn't have typedef. Is the C# tag correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are coming from C++, because the naming and syntax is C++ and not C#. In C# it would be natural to use a class (you can also use a C# struct - just change the class keyword to struct):

```
class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

With that class you can use linq to create a list:

```
var people = (
from s in myList
let split = s.Split('-')
select new Person
{
  FirstName = split.First(),
  LastName = split.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault() ?? ""
}).ToList();
```

The `let` expression makes the string split once and then reuses the result of the split.

Comment: replace *s.Fist();* with *split.First(),*

Answer (score 2):

```
var foos = list.Select(x => new PersonStruct() {
    firstname = x.Split("-")[0],
    lastname = x.Split("-")[1],
}).ToList();
```